# Get TCP response from server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have a program (.exe) that gets certain info from a server, and I wanted to be able to get that info from the command line too. I started netcat and listened on the port the program uses to communicate with its target, because I wanted to know what "requests" to make from a script, and I received this over netcat, plain text:

```
net.tcp://[my ip address]:41012/Lapis.Btouch/ServerInfo
```

I tried sending exactly that to the target (replacing my IP for its IP) using socket.send() but it wouldn't return anything. What does that mean and how can I get the data?

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('[server ip address]',41012))

while True:
 s.send('net.tcp://[server ip address]:41012/Lapis.Btouch/ServerInfo')
 response = s.recv(1024)
 print response

s.close()
```

That's the code I'm using to send the request to the target server. It won't return anything, so I think I'm not making the request in the right way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What error are you getting currently? Like the loop never terminates? Also, what does s.connect return? Is the socket connection created successfully?

Comment: Yes, the connection is established, but no response at all from server. It just stays open.

Comment: Did you send the correct end of message character(s), whatever they are? (Could be nuls, newline, carriage return, some combination.)

Comment: No, but I don't think that's the issue. I google'd a bit and found out that "net.tcp://" is something Windows .NET uses, so (from what I understood), it's a wrapper for TCP that only works in that software. However, is there any other way of getting the data without having to use the .exe?

Comment: If your problem solved, please answer your question and share your knowledge with us.

Answer (score 0):

Try capture your network packet on port `41012`, via tcpdump or wireshark or ...

Then check:

1. does your code send the request?
2. does the response returned to you?

If the answer for question (1) is False, problem is side of you and your machine. so go and solve it (review your code, check your firewall and ...)

If the answer of question (1) is True, but server doesn't send any response (this case often not happened) review your request format (check you URL or test it via browser or ...). also based on the server you connect to, maybe needed to your machine's IP recognized for server (I mean some server only give response to requests, that come from known IP addresses, in this case you need introduce yourself to server (e.g. add your IP to trusted list on server), before sending request)

Last case, if answer of both questions are correct (I guess it's your problem), you most correct your code (`response = s.recv(1024)`) why do you used `1024` for your response length?. Use correct and accurate parameters.

In python exist several methods for receiving response via socket (from server), search stackoverflow and you can find useful tips and commands. commands like  use non-blocking ways, ascync ways and ...

Comment: 1 is correct. 2 isn't. The server won't return anything, it'll just keep the connection. I don't know if sending that value is the way of getting the data I want, it's just what the .exe asked for when I made it connect to netcat.

Comment: Try to open your URL in browser, if you don't receive any response, URL is not correct. I think maybe .exe pass parameters in POST method. so use wireshark and see the content which sent to server by .exe